# anylogic selectblock on 'true' returns same agent

Tags: anylogic, vehicle-routing

I am simulating last-mile delivery and I want to iteratively evaluate the co2 emissions between stops. The numbers of the first route evaluation add up i.e. it correctly counts/removes each stop embedded within the route. The problem is that when the first route is finished, the model should consider the next route embedded in a new agent of type 'Order', in 'toConsumer' but it does not. From what I can see, is that the order agent is not updated after the condition in the select block has been met. I am not sure however, why it does this. When the condition is satisfied the agent does continue to the sink. Does anybody know how i can ensure this updating of the agent?

The anylogic model looks as follows:
[image]

In the source block I create agents following optimization results via:

```
int r = 0;
agent.routeVeh = (int) parVehicle.get(r);
agent.route = (List) parRoute.get(r);
agent.routeDep = (int) parDepot.get(r); 
r++;
```

And in the select block i have:

[image]

[image]

The to consumer block:

Comment: So, there are zero agents following the `False` option in the `routeFinished` block?

Comment: Or does it return to `toConsumer` block, but does not do the next trip?

Comment: Hi Yashar, the second one. Upon true the same route is returned to the toConsumer block.

Comment: Got it. Could you please add what is happening inside `toConsumer` block.

Comment: I added it, the - 1 is due a connection with python where the first consumer 1 is 0 in the java script.

Comment: Thanks, does this flow happen in the Main agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this operation in the Main agent, you need to define `routeCount` and `consumerCount` inside your Order agent (or if you have a Vehicle agent defined, inside that). Because they are defined for each order. Then in the `routeFinished` you need update the variable as `agent.consumerCount++;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. Much appreciated!